# Rubik cube number of alternative solutions

Tags: rubiks-cube

If a cube is in a configuration that requires 20 moves to solve, is that  sequence unique, or are there multiple sequences that arrive at a solution? That is: are there are two or more sequences that only have the start and finish position in common?

Comment: define "sequence"? Can I do "rotate this layer, unrotate, rotate, unrotate" to create a new sequence?

Comment: A sequence is 20 moves resulting in a solved cube.

Comment: Okay, exactly 20?

Comment: I would say $20$ or less. Otherwise, consider a cube with a solution of 18 moves, and start by doing/undoing anything gives several different solutions already.

Comment: Since there are more sequences of $20$ moves than there are positions of the cube, many of these will be non-unique. However, whether there are positions whose shortest solution is unique is another matter. Consider a cube where a single move has been made. There is only one way to restore it in one move.

Comment: @MarkBennet's comment I feel is the most elegant answer so far... proof w/o construction!

Answer (score 4):

Of course there can be multiple possible solutions.

Before it was proved (via computer search) that every position required 20 moves or less, the [Superflip](http://www.speedsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Superflip) was shown to require exactly 20 moves to solve.  (See also [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superflip).)  One sequence of moves which solves the Superfilp is

```
U R2 F B R B2 R U2 L B2 R U' D' R2 F R' L B2 U2 F2
```

However, the Superflip is symmetric in both rotations of the cube and in reflections of the cube.  Therefore, one can modify the above sequence of moves to solve the position in a variety of other ways.
For example:

```
U' L2 F' B' L' B2 L' U2 R' B2 L' U D L2 F' L R' B2 U2 F2 (reflection)
R D2 F B D B2 D R2 U B2 D R' L' D2 F D' U B2 R2 F2       (rotation)
```

Also, the Superflip when executed twice, results in the solved cube.  So the reverse sequence works also:

```
F2 U2 B2 L' R F' R2 D U R' B2 L' U2 R' B2 R' B' F' R2 U' (reverse)
```

In summary, employing various kinds of symmetry you can easily generate multiple sequences for solving the same position.

**Notes**

- Reflecting the cube across a plane parallel to faces `R` and `L` interchanges `U` with `U'`, `D` with `D'`, `F` with `F'`, `B` with `B'`, `R` with `L'`, and `L'` with `R'`.  This was used to generate the reflection sequence.
- Rotating the cube with axis perpendicular to `F` and `B` is just a cycle on the faces `R`, `U`, `L`, `D`.
- Reversing a sequence of moves is done by writing the sequence in reverse order and interchanging clockwise (no `'`) with counterclockwise (`'`).
- I have verified by computer that the above sequences of moves all generate / solve the Superflip.

Answer (score 3):

Of course: consider symetry, for example:

[a symetric pattern http://math.cos.ucf.edu//~reid/Rubik/Images/pons_asinorum.gif](http://math.cos.ucf.edu//~reid/Rubik/Images/pons_asinorum.gif)

[solution!](http://math.cos.ucf.edu//~reid/Rubik/patterns.html)

Comment: I should give you the benefit of doubt, and assume that you have checked this is solvable, but still I have to ask. Have you? All cube's aren't solvable.

Comment: the solution is [here](http://math.cos.ucf.edu//~reid/Rubik/patterns.html) :)

Comment: okay that satisfies me. +1 :D

Comment: The most simple example is the first one, of course. I made the switch.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand how solving patterns has any bearing on my question. I have been told that the cube can always be solved in 20 moves or less. My question is: is that 20 move solution unique? My conjecture is: no its not unique.

Comment: @user3111005 mookid says that *since* this symmetric cube can be solved, you can mirror one solution to create a new solution. He proved your conjecture. Not unique. His link proves that the cube can in fact be solved.

Comment: This site: http//:www.cube20.org describes the "20 moves required" positions (they need "God's algorithm" apparently). It doesn't mention alternatives. Maybe alternative sequences are not possible. I feel I'm homing in on an answer...